# how can I rewrite URL to fancy url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post, get

when my user logs in, I want the get variables that were sent rewrote onto the URL like so:

http://mysite.com/mygetvar1/mygetvar_value1/mygetvar2/mygetvar_value2/

or

mysite.com/mygetvar1=mygetvar_value1/mygetvar2=mygetvar_value2/

How can I do this?
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) can offer you like that. Many other PHP frameworks offer that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteRule /([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /login.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [R=301]
RewriteRule /([^/]*)=([^/]*)/([^/]*)=([^/]*)/ /login.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [R=301]
```

Comment: I will appreciate you if you guide me that can i add two rewrite condition is one .htaccess file. My htaccess file working properly but i need to rewrite in same file. I want to rewrite this URL (http://www.example.ae/index.php?route=common/thispage) to (http://www.example.ae/thispage)

Comment: @Mr.Developer please add another question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need the mod_rewrite module enable.

After, put this in your config file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ads/(rims|tires|combo)/([0-9]+)/(.+).html     /ad.php?noAds=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This is a example.
Your url will look like : http://www.yourwebsite.com/ads/rims/331/title.html
but you will call the url : http//www.yourwebsite.com/ad.php?noAds=331

For your regex , you should use a site like http://www.rubular.com

You can use the .htaccess file or put in directly in the httpd.conf file